# basic java template method

Tags: java, templates

I want to write a function such that I will have 2 objects, and I will attempt to merge them, where if the 2nd object is not null, return 2nd. Otherwise return first object (doesn't matter if it is null or not.

Here's the code I came up with:

```
public <T> T merge (Class<T> x, Class<T> y){
    if (y!= null) return (T) y;
    else return (T) x;
}
```

but I get a warning for casting:
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class to T

I'm wondering if this should be the right way to write it, or is there a better way?

If the 2 objects passed is from the same class, then I would just return the 2nd class. It could also be the case of a class and a null, and I would like to return the one where the class is not null. If both class is null, then I would just return null.

There's no other cases where I pass in 2 different classes.

Comment: Your parameters are not T type but T *class* types, but you are not returning this but rather T *instances* -- big difference. Do you mean to return: `return y.newInstance();` and visa versa for x, instead? Your code and question are confusing to say the least.

Comment: Change the arguments of type `T` not `Class<T>` (I assume you want to return objects not classes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your method to this:

```
public <T> T merge (T x, T y){
    if (y!= null) return y;
    else return x;
}
```

You original method takes in variables with the type of "Class" yet you are returning a object of type T. Thus the compiler warns you about type casting safety.

Comment: Or `return (y == null) ? x : y`.

Answer (score 1):

Why is your argument list using `Class<T>` instead of just `T`?

You want to return an instance of `T`, not the `T` `class`.

The compiler is warning you because you're not returning what's expected.

Here's a working example:

```
public <T> T merge (T x, T y){
   if (y != null) {
    return y;
   }
   else {
        T merged = null;
        // TODO merge code
        return merged;
   }
}
```